# How to pass outgoing email from server to another server and send?

Tags: linux, centos, smtp

Is this possible? if yes, can you please guide me on how to do this?

SERVER 1 => 
this where my email form and pass to server 2

SERVER 2 => 
; the server who will act as bridge between "SERVER1" and "SERVER2" 
; who will send the outgoing mails from "SERVER1"

SERVER 3 => 
the SMTP Server

Comment: What is your real-world situation that you need this for?

Comment: This is a really open ended question.  Of particular significance is omission of the detail as to whether or not either or both SERVER 2 and SERVER 3 requires authentication or use of secure protocols (as this can significantly increase the complexity of an answer).  The implementation can also be affected if either server implements some form of spam prevention.  The OP may find that a useful answer is more likely to result if additional details are provided.